# pyodbc errors when querying datetime column returns NULL value

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, sybase

I'm connecting to a SYBASE database using pyodbc and querying a table that has NULL values for some **datetime** attributes:

> month must be in 1..12

The attribute Type is defined as 'datetime' in the table, but as I mentioned it may be NULL.
The error happens in

```
self.cursor.execute(stored_proc, params)
```

I get the error when the cursor attempts to fetch a record with NULL.
How can I configure pyodbc in a way that it can ignore NULL values for datetime?
I didn't find anything in it's document:
[pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Data-Types)

I have the following connection code:

```
self.conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};SERVER={};UID={};PWD={};PORT=1234;'.format(self.db_config['driver'],self.db_config['server'], self.db_config['id'], self.db_config['pass']),autocommit=True)
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/ac16abd908b15ca3039db0d8de917a85) works for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @GordThompson here is the values I get: 
pyodbc version: 4.0.30
Adaptive Server Enterprise (ANSI)
SQL_DRIVER_VER: 15.7.0.1300

Comment: But do you get the same error as before when you run my example?

Comment: Yes, this is what I got:
Adaptive Server Enterprise (ANSI)
15.7.0.1300

    results = self.cursor.execute("SELECT id, dtm FROM mas").fetchall()
ValueError: month must be in 1..12

I recreated your exact same code, with table name 'mas'

Comment: @GordThompson adding to my previous column, this is what I now have in the db with your script:
select * from datastore..mas;
id          dtm
1            2001-01-01 01:01:01.000
2                    NULL

and I got the 
ValueError: month must be in 1..12 //I wish I could format the code here btw

Comment: @GordThompson SQL_DBMS_NAME: SQL Server
SQL_DBMS_VER: 15.7.0

Comment: Okay, I get 'SQL Server' for SQL_DBMS_NAME, too. That's surprising.

Comment: I also get no error after downgrading pyodbc from 4.0.39 to 4.0.30. :(

Comment: would it be possible that my SQL_DBMS_VER needs to get updated? how about SQL_DRIVER_VER?
I don't know what to do at this point.. is there a way to ignore rows with NULL value for datetime using a different method? @GordThompson

Comment: You could try something like `SELECT id, CASE WHEN dtm IS NULL THEN CAST('1753-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime) ELSE dtm END AS dtm FROM tbl` to force NULL values to `1753-01-01` and then flip them back to NULL after you retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks, COALESCE seems to be the only option.